# Iframe not showing on intel xdk android app

Tags: cordova, iframe, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I have an app built by intel xdk. Unfortunately the app does not display iframes. It only displays the iframe on the emulator and on a browser. Is there a plugin I can use or what should I do to display the iframe from an external source

this is the iframe:

```html
<iframe id="JotFormIFrame" onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" allowtransparency="true" src="https://secure.myjotform.com/form/*******" frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:1000px; border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.handleIFrameMessage = function(e) {
    var args = e.data.split(":");
    var iframe = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame");
    if (!iframe) return;
    switch (args[0]) {
      case "scrollIntoView":
        iframe.scrollIntoView();
        break;
      case "setHeight":
        iframe.style.height = args[1] + "px";
        break;
      case "collapseErrorPage":
        if (iframe.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
          iframe.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
        }
        break;
      case "reloadPage":
        window.location.reload();
        break;
    }
  };
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", handleIFrameMessage, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleIFrameMessage);
  }
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.click on projects(top left)

2.go to build settings

3.on domain list

add myjotform.com

or secure.myjotform.com (maybe both)